# How to get values from stripe return in ruby controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting a return from stripe and trying to parse it and am apparently doing it incorrectly.

Code in stripe_webhooks.rb controller

```
@event_data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
```

When I log that is is the full return.  However when I try to access any of the values like this(this is how it is set up in the tutorial I am working from)

```
@event_data.data.object.id
```

I get the error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `data' for #<Hash:0x007fe533bebe08>):
```

What I need to access (among other things) is the id from the charge, not the first id which is for the event .  So the id with "ch_..." in it from the output below.

Log of the output

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"evt_19DMt92cKHX9k3v0rcdvLs5a", "object"=>"event", "api_version"=>"2014-03-28", "created"=>1478562655, "data"=>{"object"=>{"id"=>"ch_19DMt92cKHX9k3v0iQKMEHDu", "object"=>"charge",...
```

If anyone could shed some light on how to access the data that is inside the "data => {"object" =>{ " section it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a hash. Did you try using hash accessors `@event_data["data"]["object"]["id"]`?

Comment: Honestly I don't know much about it and was unsure what it was called exactly that I was trying to do, I will give that a try and look into hash accessors.

Comment: I put some useful links in my answer so you can have some references to the terms and approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to access the Hash you're loading by using [bracket accessors](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D).

```
@event_data["data"]["object"]["id"]`
```

which will give you what you're looking for.

Also many times ruby code prefers to use [symbols](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html), which means you can use

```
@event_data = JSON.parse(request.body.read).with_indifferent_access
```

to access the same content via

```
@event_data[:data][:object][:id]
```

Note these solutions do not handle missing values, in which case you'll need to guard against accessors returning `nil` instead of the structure you defined.

Comment: @Rockwell Rice additionally, you can use the dot syntax once you instantiate a `Stripe::Charge` object as per [the Stripe ruby documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#retrieve_charge)